# For the past few days I’ve been having problems with my reading list on safari on my iPad

Tags: ipad

For the past few days I’ve been having problems with my reading list on safari on my iPad. When I go to my reading list, the search browser on the reading list is gone. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Did you scroll right to the top? It's not there until you do.

Comment: I did that like 10 times for the past few days.

Comment: You have to tell us exactly what you've tried & what the results were, to save people going over the same ground. Precise iPad model & current iPadOS may also be useful. Please add detail to your question via the [Edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/441845/edit) button underneath.

Comment: I’m new at this so I’ll explain it as hard as I can. I go to my reading list and I always use the search browser that’s on my reading list. But for the past few days the search browser on the reading list just disappeared. I try scrolling up and down But it still doesn’t come back. I even tried resetting safari on my iPad but still nothing.